# The listener supports no services

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I installed Oracle Database 11gR2 as well as Oracle Grid Infrastructure on a Linux box, then I created the `orcl` database.

I have always been able to connect to my database using SQL*Plus or OEM. But lately, I'm facing an issue when typing the command `lsnrctl status`, and so I'm not able to connect to the database.

My `listener.ora` file:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pc.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

My tnsnames.ora file :

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pc.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.example.com)
    )
  )
```

When typing `lsnrctl status`, I get the following :

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 21-JUL-2014 03:35:48

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                21-JUL-2014 03:25:58
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 9 min. 50 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/pc151/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=pc.company.com)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

---

When typing `sqlplus / as sysdba` then `startup`, I get this :

```
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-01565: error in identifying file '+DATA/orcl/spfileorcl.ora'
ORA-17503: ksfdopn:2 Failed to open file +DATA/orcl/spfileorcl.ora
ORA-29701: unable to connect to Cluster Synchronization Service
```

And the `srvctl start database` command fails to start the database up too.

My `oratab` file is the following :

```
#Backup file is  /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/srvm/admin/oratab.bak.pc150 line added by Agent
#

# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
# a database.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#
+ASM:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/grid:N
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N          # line added by Agent
```

Comment: Is your database actually running? It won't appear in the services list until it registers, which it does at startup if it can, and it keeps trying if it can't. If it is up - you can connect locally with SQL*Plus - do you have the `local_listener` init parameter set; and does `pc.company.com` resolve to your PC's actual IP address (i.e. you aren't using DHCP)?

Comment: My database is not running unfortunately, and I'm not using dhcp. I have a static IP address.

Answer (score 22):

The database registers its service name(s) with the listener when it starts up. If it is unable to do so then it tries again periodically - so if the listener starts after the database then there can be a delay before the service is recognised.

If the database isn't running, though, nothing will have registered the service, so you shouldn't expect the listener to know about it - `lsnrctl status` or `lsnrctl services` won't report a service that isn't registered yet.

You can start the database up without the listener; from the Oracle account and with your `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_SID` and `PATH` set you can do:

```
sqlplus /nolog
```

Then from the SQL*Plus prompt:

```
connect / as sysdba
startup
```

Or through the Grid infrastructure, from the grid account, use the [`srvctl start database` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/rac.112/e41960/srvctladmin.htm#RACAD5032):

```
srvctl start database -d db_unique_name [-o start_options] [-n node_name]
```

You might want to look at whether the database is set to auto-start in your `oratab` file, and depending on what you're using whether it should have started automatically. If you're expecting it to be running and it isn't, or you try to start it and it won't come up, then that's a whole different scenario - you'd need to look at the error messages, alert log, possibly trace files etc. to see exactly why it won't start, and if you can't figure it out, maybe ask on Database Adminsitrators rather than on Stack Overflow.

---

If the database can't see `+DATA` then ASM may not be running; you can [see how to start that  here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e18951/asminst.htm#OSTMG94084); or using [`srvctl start asm`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/rac.112/e41960/srvctladmin.htm#RACAD5036). As the documentation says, make sure you do that from the grid home, not the database home.

Comment: It failed to start asm by issuing srvctl start asm ! My listener.ora file is located in the grid home and not the database home, is that normal ?

Comment: Yes, that is normal. Please add the error you get from the ASM start to the question. You started ASM from the grid home, right? Might be worth looking into the ASM status and disk status, depending on what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your `ORACLE_HOME` definition in your listener.ora file. Right now its not registered with any `ORACLE_HOME`.

Sample listener.ora

```
abc =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.kma.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_abc =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (ORACLE_HOME= /abc/DbTier/11.2.0)
      (SID_NAME = abc)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

for listener support no services you can use the following command to set local_listener paramter in your spfile use your listener port and server ip address

alter system set local_listener='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.1.101)(PORT=1520)))' sid='testdb' scope=spfile;

Answer (score 0):

you need to reconfigure your tnsnames.ora so that it can point to your hostname
after that listener will be able to pick the new hostname. after which check the status of your listener lsnrctl status and start listener lsnrctl start
then register your listener. Alter system register

Answer (score 0):

Check local_listener definition in your spfile or pfile. In my case, the problem was with pfile, I had moved the pfile from a similar environment and it had LISTENER_sid as LISTENER and not just LISTENER.